# Symfony difference between website-skeleton And framework-standard-edition

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a beginner in Symfony and I want to know what the differences between these two commands for creating a new project in Symfony.

using website-skeleton :

```
    composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton first-project
```

using framework-standard-edition :

```
    composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition first-project
```

Comment: Hi, which Symfony version do you want?

Comment: Hi, I want just to know what the difference, because that confusing me!

Comment: What happens if you run both commands and simply compare the results?

Comment: website-skeleton is the current version (4.4 or 5.0 or something). framework-standard-edition is the quite old version (3.4.x).

Comment: Did you mean composer create-project symfony/skeleton first_project vs composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton first-project ?

Comment: @FrankB yes I mean it!

Comment: So the  symfony/skeleton is a minimized version of the symfony framework and you will have to add a lot of composer packages manually when using it for a standard website project where the website-skeleton includes a lot of packages out of the box. See the both composer.json files to see the differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the composer create-project command looks up the entry on packagist that correlates to the second parameter.

So `symfony/website-skeleton` points to: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/website-skeleton while `symfony/framework-standard-edition` points to: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/framework-standard-edition which in turn point to their respective repositories on github, which may have different names (as is the case with the framework-standard-edition one)

Those pages contain the version numbers that are being installed. The website-skeleton uses symfony/flex (which adds its own definition to the composer.json in the `flex-require` section which is not shown on packagist, since it's non-standard stuff), which is not quite informative.

The website-skeleton is the bootstrap for a website on the current version of symfony (which may change in the future, so it may reference a static version at some point in the future or may restrict the version number in some way), which should be symfony 5 right now.

The framework-standard-edition is the bootstrap for a website on the old 3.4.x version of symfony, which probably won't change, since it's already restricted on the version number.

If you're starting on a new project with no restriction to an old php version, you should prefer the website-skeleton.